# Largest graph of max degree $n$ such that every two nodes of distance $k$ are connected by at least $k$ distinct paths

Tags: graph-theory

Question: Suppose I have a graph where every node has degree at most $n$. Suppose two nodes are "on good terms" if there exists a number $k$ such that they are connected by at least $k$ paths of length $k$ such that no two such paths share any internal nodes. What is the maximal size of a graph such that every node is "on good terms" with every other node?

My work: Doing the casework for small cases, it appears that the maximal size of such a graph is given by $2^n$. For small numbers of vertices (1,2,3), it appears the best I can do is by taking the vertices and edges of $[0,1]^n$. I'm not confident in this answer and I feel like I'm missing something that will show up in higher dimensions.

My question: Am I on the right track? If so, what's a good strategy to prove this? If not, what improvements can I make?